# Does the magnitude change across the twisted wavefront?

Tags: optics, waves

I am currently studying *Optics*, fifth edition, by Hecht. Chapter **2.11 Twisted Light** says the following:

> [image]
> Such beams have what’s called an *azimuthal ($\phi$) phase dependence*. Looking down the central axis toward the source the phase changes with angle, just as the time on a clock face changes with the angle $\phi$ between the vertical 12–6 line and the minute hand. If a component-wave peak occurs at 12, as in Fig. 2.32, a trough might occur directly beneath the axis at 6. Examine the diagram carefully, noticing that as it goes from 12 to 1 to 2 to 3 and so on the wavelets advance. Their phases are all different on the slice; they’re each shifted successively by $\pi/6$. The disc-shaped slice cuts across the beam but it is not a surface of constant phase, and the overall disturbance is not a plane wave. Still the component sinusoids (all of wavelength $\lambda$) are correlated and all of their peaks lie along a spiral.
> [image]
> Now rather than having the wavelets intersect the disc on a single circle, suppose them to be multiplied in number so that they fill the disc; the constant-phase spiral line will sweep out a twisted surface that looks like an elongated flat spring (e.g., an Archimedes’ screw or a stretched Slinky). That surface of constant phase is a wavefront.
> Let’s extend Fig. 2.32 to form a beam, overlooking the fact that a real beam would expand as it traveled forward. Figure 2.33 shows a number of wavelets displaced in space, all of which reach their peak values on the wavefront, which is an advancing *helicoid* that winds forward once per $\lambda$ (that’s the pitch of the helix) while traveling at the speed of light. This particular helicoidal wavefront happens to correspond to a maximum (i.e., wavelet peaks); it could have had any value. Since the beam is monochromatic, there will be a nested progression of twisted wavefronts immediately entwined behind it, each of a slightly different phase and magnitude, changing from one to the next sinusoidally.

Does the magnitude actually change across the twisted wavefront? This isn't clear to me from figure 2.33.

[image]

Image from user Göran Forssell's answer at https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-the-amplitude-and-the-magnitude-of-sine-waves